# Modifying the CSS steps() function

Tags: css, css-animations

So the steps() animation looks like this (apologies for the hand-drawn graph):

[image: steps]

It kind of looks like a staircase, with the sudden shifts in displacement. What if I wanted the transitions between steps to be a bit more... *gradual*? Something like this:

[image: steps2]

So even though it's still a staircase, it's definitely less sudden in the shift in displacement.

Is it possible to create an animation based on steps that looks like the second image? Ideally I'd like to have it based off steps so that I don't have to hardcode in all the percentages manually.

Comment: Please, provide a working example of "actual behaviour", and then we can try to "smooth" your animation

Answer (score -1):

Yes, potentially you can use CSS cubic bezier in order to customize your timing function.

Please bare in mind it is an experimental technology.

http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2011/03/11/understanding-css-cubic-bezier/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: Please guys add a comment when down-voting. Thanks!